# "amplify push" creates new varaibles in type at AWS Appsync - React Native

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When I do `amplify push` , I get a few variables in the Appsync Schema.

This is from schema.graphql in react native amplify/backend folder.

```
type Botdata @model (subscriptions: null){
  client_id: String!
  id: String!
  lock_status: Float
}
```

And this is what I get on the Appsync Schema after  `amplify push`

```
type Botdata {
   client_id: String!
   id: String!
   lock_status: Float
   createdAt: AWSDateTime!
   updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
   _version: Int!
   _deleted: Boolean
   _lastChangedAt: AWSTimestamp!
}
```

This causes my undefined type error for the entire operation. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you was turn on Optimistic Concurrency. This helpful when you have conflict data version between app and database but you need:

- Check _version when you use mutation if _version on app different _version field of row data on Database then operation mutation you return error.

If you don't need Optimistic Concurrency you can turn of that:

- go to folder project open command line with administrator.
- run: `amplify update api`
- choose: `graphql`
- choose: `Disable conflict detection`
- update api to cloud: amplify push
  Hope my answer helpful for you.